# Add Multiple Instances

Tags: php

So I have this code that detects what page the user is on and then spits out a class of "active" if necessary.

```
<li <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
```

So just to clarify, this code checks if the url has index.php in it, and if it does, it spits out the "active" class. What I need to do and don't know how to is add multiple instances to this code. So instead of just detecting index.php it needs to be able to detect other pages like about.php for example.

Sorry if this comes a very simple question to most of you but I am new to PHP.

Comment: please explain how you are making the list. Manual or is it formed using an array, etc

Comment: manual. I just need to be able for the page to detect the page they are on and then do something based on their page... i.e. echo "class='active'"

Comment: Ok so just paste that line, and replace index with about. Does that code snippet work for you?

Comment: So just do the PHP code as many times as I need changing the link to check ALL in the <li> tag?

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand. For example, if I wanted to check if their is index.php AND about.php in a url and if their is echo out "class='active'", how would I do that?

Comment: SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] looks at what the URI is on page load. If it is index.php add `class="active"` if not, dont add.

Answer (score 1):

Split your code from the layout.

Possible solution:

```
   <?php 
    $active_flags = array('index.php','about.php','test.php');
    $active = '';
    foreach($active_flags as $item) {
        if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$item)!==false) {
           $active='active';
           break;
        }
    }
    ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $active?>">Your list Item</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As you are listing manually  you just enter this one it really help you
<li  
 if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php'))
          {
             echo 'class="active"';
          }
          else
          {
              echo 'class="inactive"';
          }
</li>
```